# Javascript closures in generat ID

Tags: javascript, closures

```
var generateID=function() {
    var prefix="uid-";
    var count=0;

    return function(){
        count+=1;
        console.log(prefix+count)
    }
}
var create = generateID();

console.log(create());
console.log(create());
console.log(create());
```

Expected output:
uid-1
uid-2
uid-3

Help me in undefined error part in output.

Comment: You're calling `console.log` in two different places

Answer (score 1):

create doesn't return anything so if you `console.log(create())` it prints undefined

```js
var generateID=function() {
    var prefix="uid-";
    var count=0;

    return function(){
        count+=1;
        console.log(prefix+count)
    }
}
var create = generateID();

create()
create()
create()

var generateID2 = function() {
    var prefix="uid-";
    var count=0;

    return function(){
        count+=1;
        return prefix+count
    }
}
var create2 = generateID2();

console.log(create2())
console.log(create2())
console.log(create2())
```

Answer (score 1):

The `create` function does not return any value. This is why `console.log(create());` calls log `undefined`.

```
return function() {
    count+=1;
    return prefix+count;
}
```